# Does there exist $n$ such that all numbers $n,2n,\dots,2000n$ have the same digits?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

> Does there exist a number $n$ such that all numbers $n, 2n, 3n, 4n, \dots, 2000n$ have the same multi-sets of digits except zeroes?

(Having the same multi-sets of digits excepts zeroes means having equal number of ones, twos, ... , nines in the decimal expansion.)

A related question was already [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/782413/regularities-when-n-and-2n-contain-the-same-digits) on MathSE, but the answers there does not provide an approach suitable for bigger numbers like 2000.

Comment: This question was asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314895/nonabelian-global-symmetries-son-symmetric-theory-of-n-scalar-fields) in a bizarre way: instead of asking a new question, the OP changed his old question completely. I didn't notice that and after having solved the problem I found the question disappeared. But I believe it is interesting. And since the OP does not post the question, I've decided to ask - and answer - it myself.

Comment: How about $n=0$?

Comment: Biggest coincidence ever. I was checking [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447797/2013-usamo-problem-5) out just a few minutes back.

Comment: I haven't done it yet, but the same idea is perhaps applicable.

Comment: I'll post an answer soon :) I'll check how it relates to the link later.

Comment: If 2n and n have the same digits except zero than 20n, 200n, 2000n, and 20000000000000000000n will.  If by "bigger" you mean "multiplied by higher powers of 10" the approach for bigger numbers wasn't provided because it is utterly trivial.

Comment: I have yet to find a solution that utilizes $10$ is a primitive root modulo $7^k$.

Comment: It does need to be clarified whether same digits mean the same digits the same number of times.  I think there are too many trivial or arbitrary solutions to make repeating digits a reasonable option.  But then I'm utterly flummoxed as to why the OP thought specifying a difference of 2n and 2000n was nescessary.

Comment: @rah4927, this is a correct approach :) But $7^k$ is bad since $7n$ will not have the same digits

Comment: I've added the word "multisets" to the formulation. Which means same digits same number of times

Comment: @zhoraster If you add "multi-set" in the OP then you really ought to define it in the OP.  I had to look up multiset and it seems to mean the exact *opposite* of what you claim.  The multiple occurances are okay.  Also I still don't understand why you are asking about 2000n vs. 2n.  Sure that is utterly trivial?

Comment: @fleablood, yes, $2$ and $2000$ is trivial. But it is the way it was asked originally. I don't know what you mean by "opposite to my claim".

Comment: Okay, the way it was originally asked was n, 2n, and 2000n.  and not "all multiples up to 2000" so now it makes a lot of sense.  But doesn't a multiset allow multiple instances of elements?  mwv's example that 10 and 1110 or 243 and 342443 would both be in the same multiset, wouldn't they.

Comment: @fleablood The problem with $2000n$ is not harder than the problem with $2n$ because of $2000n$. Rather, it is that $1999n$ must also have the right digits ...

Comment: @fleablood, no. These are the same sets (or "power-sets"), but not multi-sets.

Comment: Ah, I see.  The definition of a multiset is that the *set* may have multiple elements.  Thus you are saying that the digits *are* the multiset rather than merely *from* the set.  I'm not familiar with the concept of multiset so using the term did not make things clearer.

Comment: Btw, you might want to delay accepting an answer. Early acceptance may discourage other users from contributing further.Of course, its your own choice but it usually lowers the productivity on the site.

Comment: @rah4927, you are right. Next time I will wait some time to accept.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose $N>2000$ is an integer such that the period length of the (eventually) repeating $\frac1N$ equals $N$. Then in computing the decimal expansion all remainders $1,\ldots,N-1$ occur at some place. Then the fractions $\frac1N,\frac2N,\ldots, \frac{2000}N$ turn out to lead to the very same period, merely shifted.
In this situation,  we have $\frac1N=\frac n{10^{N-1}-1}$ for some $1\le n< 10^N-1$ and conclude that $n,2n,\ldots,2000n$ indeed are obtained by rotating the digit sequences suitably (taking an appropriate number of leading zeroes into account).

(Actually, it would be sufficient that the remainders $1,2,\ldots,2000$ occur during the computation of the period, so the period length *might* be smaller than $N$.)

The question is: Do such $N$ exist?
Primes are good candidates (for any other $N$, the order of $10$ cannot exceed $\phi(N)$). So for which primes $N$ is $10$ of order $N-1$? One such prime is $2017$ and that is $>2000$, thius solving the concrete problem - or rather
$$ n=\frac{10^{2016}-1}{2017}=\underbrace{4957858205\ldots233019335647}_{2013\text{ digits}}
$$
is. Intriguingly, each of the digits $1,2,4,5,7,8$ occurs $202$ times, each of $3,6,9$ occurs $201$ times in that $n$.
In fact, it turns out that $2017$ is the smallest prime $>2000$ with this property. As additionally, $\phi(n)<2000$ for all composites $<2017$, we see that $2017$ is the smallest $N$ for which the above construction works. However, this does not completely rule out that smaller $n$ exist (where  the $kn$ only "accidentally" have the same digit statistics).

See also sequence [Full reptend primes](http://oeis.org/A001913) in OEIS.

Comment: Nice. Didn't expect that $2017$ works already.

Comment: @mvw Darn, why would you even check such a thing? :)

Comment: Checking is next. Then I might start trying to understand how it works. :-)

Comment: @mvw, you can check my number (it is for a different $p$, but I wrote all digits for your convenience :) ).

Answer (score 9):

The answer is positive. Moreover, there exists a number $n$ such that additionally all numbers $2n,3n,\dots,2000n$ are obtained from $n$ by cyclic permutation of digits (naturally, we need to add some zeroes before $n$ for that). Here is this number:

```
0004330879168471199653529666522304027717626678215677782589865742745777392810740580337808575140753572975313988739714161974880900822867042009527934170636639237765266349068860978778692074491121697704634040710264183629276743178865309657860545690775227371156344737981810307492420961455175400606323083585967951494153313122563880467734950194889562581203984408834993503681247293200519705500216543958423559982676483326115201385881333910783889129493287137288869640537029016890428757037678648765699436985708098744045041143352100476396708531831961888263317453443048938934603724556084885231702035513209181463837158943265482893027284538761368557817236899090515374621048072758770030316154179298397574707665656128194023386747509744478129060199220441749675184062364660025985275010827197921177999133824166305760069294066695539194456474664356864443482026851450844521437851883932438284971849285404937202252057167605023819835426591598094413165872672152446946730186227804244261585101775660459073191857947163274144651364226938068427890861844954525768731052403637938501515807708964919878735383282806409701169337375487223906453009961022087483759203118233001299263750541359896058899956691208315288003464703334776959722823733217843222174101342572542226071892594196621914248592464270246860112602858380251190991771329579904720658293633607622347336509311390212213079255088783022953659592897358163707232568211346903421394543092247726288436552620181896925075790385448245993936769164140320485058466868774361195322650498051104374187960155911650064963187527067994802944997834560415764400173235166738847986141186660892161108705067128627111303594629709831095712429623213512343005630142919012559549588566478995236032914681680381117366825465569510610653962754439151147682979644867908185361628410567345171069727154612386314421827631009094846253789519272412299696838458207016024252923343438718059766132524902555218709398007795582503248159376353399740147249891728020788220008661758336942399307059333044608055435253356431355565179731485491554785621481160675617150281507145950627977479428323949761801645734084019055868341273278475530532698137721957557384148982243395409268081420528367258553486357730619315721091381550454742312689475963620614984841922910350801212646167171935902988306626245127760935469900389779125162407968817669987007362494586401039411
```

But how to find it?

Let us call a number $n$  $k$-cyclic if all numbers $2n,3n,\dots,kn$ are obtained from $n$ by cyclic permutation of digits. For example, $142857$ is $6$-cyclic: $2\cdot 142857 = 285714$, $3\cdot 142857 = 428571$, $4\cdot 142857 = 571428$, $5\cdot 142857 = 714285$, $6\cdot 142857 = 857142$.

The crucial step is the following observation (proof is available on request):

> Let $p$ be a prime number such that $10$ is a primitive residue modulo $p$. Then the period of the fraction $1/p$ is $(p-1)$-cyclic.

For example, $10$ is primitive root modulo $7$, and from $1/7 = 0.(142857)$ we get that $142857$ is $6$-cyclic, which we saw already.

So we are left to find a prime number $p>2000$ such that $10$ is a primitive root modulo $p$. There is a useful Chebyshev theorem:

> If $p=4q+1$ is prime, where $q$ is prime and $q = 2 \pmod 5$, then $10$ is a primitive root modulo $10$.

Now the smallest prime number greater than $2000$ and satisfying the Chebyshev theorem is $2309 = 4\cdot 577-1$. Therefore, the period of $1/2309 = 0.0004330879\dots$ is $2308$-cyclic (hence, $2000$-cyclic). This period is written above.

Comment: So if Artin's conjecture holds true, we can replace $2000$ by any other number(as noted by someone on this same problem on aops).

Comment: I just wish Artin's conjecture would be proved. I want to use it in many contest problems but can't because of its still being  a "conjecture".

Answer (score 1):

I told my friend Ruby [how to check](https://gist.github.com/f479451d39b988a8ba81) the numbers by Hagen, zhoraster and two test numbers by me (n=4212345, n=0). She did the check and got:

```
n digits:
[0:198, 1:202, 2:202, 3:201, 4:202, 5:202, 6:201, 7:202, 8:202, 9:201]
OK - congrats!

n digits:
[0:227, 1:231, 2:231, 3:231, 4:231, 5:231, 6:231, 7:231, 8:231, 9:230]
OK - congrats!

n digits:
[0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:1, 4:2, 5:1, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0]
error:
n_2 digits:
[0:1, 1:0, 2:1, 3:0, 4:2, 5:0, 6:1, 7:0, 8:1, 9:1]

n digits:
[0:1, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0]
OK - congrats!
```

We then did a little search for numbers of the form $(10^{k-1}-1)/k$ for $k$ from $1$ to $3000$. See the [log](https://gist.github.com/ddee118feb023c63b59c).